# If $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is cauchy for all $x$ in a measure space then can we say its pointwise convergent to some function?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let, $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be our measure space. Let, $f_{n}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable for all $n \ge 1$. If $\{f_n(x)\}_{n \ge 1}$ is cauchy for all $x \in X$, then can we say that $\{f_n(x)\}_{n \ge 1}$ converges to some function $g$, point wise?

I can see how to "kind of" construct the function but the only problem is that we don't know if $X$ is countable so I don't think you can specify a function with an uncountable number of points?

Comment: Note that the question is independent of the context of a measure space. Pointwise convergence only relies on the structure of the codomain. It works the same wether the function is defined in a measure space, a topological space, group, vector space, or just a plain old set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is Cauchy complete, the sequence $(f_n(x))$ converges for all $x$. Then, by definition, $f_n$ converges pointwise.

Comment: are we allowed to construct the function $g$ such that $\forall x \in X:$

$$\{f_n(x)\}_{n \ge 1} \rightarrow L,  $$

since $\{f_n(x)\}_{n \ge 1}$ is cauchy which means we can let 

g(x) = L.

Is this a "mathematically valid" way to define a function.

Comment: We can define $g(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ but most likely $g(x)$ will not be constant.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t even need a measurable structure on $X$. Let $X$ be *any* non-empty set and let $f_n:X\to\mathbb R$ be a real-valued function for each $n\in\mathbb N$. If the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ (endowed with the usual Euclidean metric) for each fixed $x\in X$, then we know that this sequence converges to some (unique) limit because $\mathbb R$ is complete. Let $g(x)$ denote that limit. By definition, then, the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of functions converges pointwise to the function $g$, that is:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=g(x)\quad\text{for every $x\in X$.}
\end{align*}